# CKEditor 5 - Using HTML inside mentions

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have been using mentions in CKEditor 5 to tag certain system variables. A typical tag looks like as:

```
<span contenteditable="false" class="mention document_variable" style="color:var(--ck-color-mention-text);" data-mention="#ApprovedCosts" data-documentid="185" data-version="-1" data-container="#Variable-tab-textarea" href="javascript:void(0)">
    #ApprovedCosts
</span>
```

When I try to render the following (the idea is to show the variable value when the user clicks preview, while he continues editing):

```
<span contenteditable="false" class="mention document_variable" style="color:var(--ck-color-mention-text);" data-mention="#ApprovedCosts" data-documentid="185" data-version="-1" data-container="#Variable-tab-textarea" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <p>Nice rendered <b>html</b></p>
</span>
```

CKEditor goes bonkers.

My requirement is to show a nicely formatted variable name inside the tag. I know I can control via CSS, but there could be a situation where I might end-up rendering a small table (if variable points to a data set), etc.

Help will be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Can we have more information .. like eg this example you mention with the table. It would help to make the problem / question more specific.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, CKEditor 5 documentations refrain from going with your basic plain HTML approach, as seen in the [comments](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/examples/framework/chat-with-mentions.html#source-code):

> This plugin customizes the way mentions are handled in the editor model and data.
> Instead of a classic `<span class="mention"></span>,`

Within their [mentions documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html) (by the way, highly suggested to take a look at - it's very well documented with lots of useful examples in case you're stuck!), they're defining a ClassicEditor (*to be precise, they want to mimic a chat platform in which you can tag a user and will receive a list of users in return*).

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '.chat__editor' ), {
        extraPlugins: [ Essentials, Paragraph, Mention, MentionLinks, Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough, Link ],
        toolbar: {
            items: [
                'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', '|', 'link', '|', 'undo', 'redo'
            ]
        },
        mention: {
            feeds: [
                {
                    marker: '@',
                    feed: [
                        { id: '@cflores', avatar: 'm_1', name: 'Charles Flores' },
                        [...]
                    ],
                    itemRenderer: customItemRenderer
                    [...]
```

After the mention object is created, they're calling the `customItemRenderer` function. This infrastructure could nearly identical be copied. For your part the function `MentionLinks` is important, as you can customize how mentions are handled, i.e. let's take a look at their example:

```
function MentionLinks( editor ) {
   editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' ).elementToAttribute( {
        view: {
            name: 'a',
            key: 'data-mention',
            classes: 'mention',
            attributes: {
                href: true
            }
        },
        model: {
            key: 'mention',
            value: viewItem => editor.plugins.get( 'Mention' ).toMentionAttribute( viewItem )
        },
        converterPriority: 'high'
    } );
```

Basically, you can customize all the properties within the `MentionLinks` function. CKEditor 5 did a good job documenting the `mention` plugin very hierarchically:

[image: Hierarchy] *The documentation can be found [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_mention_mention-Mention.html).*

---

On a slight off-topic note I noticed your code passage `<p>Nice rendered <b>html</b><p>` contains little formality issues, i.e. you need to  close the `<p>` tag by assigning a close tag `</p>`:

```
<p>Nice rendered <b>html</b></p>
```

*Though I'm pretty sure that's not the error as you're talking about HTML in general and not only this code passage.*

Answer (score 0):

I think your main issue is your tags.  Your paragraph tags (`<p>`) don't have a closing tag, only two opening tags. It should be `<p>***your text here***</p>`. If this doesn't fix the issue, please leave a comment.

Comment: `<b>` is definitely not a self closing tag! What you are referring to is `<br>` (break), though the OP doesn't use `<br>` whatsoever.